# Which gcc O2 option do this constant folding？

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, javac

I am not familiar with gcc,this code:

```
int a=145;int b=267+a;
printf("%d/n",b);
```

if comiple with no optimize option,will use the "addl" command,but if open O2 option,it will show me 412 direct.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

there are so many O2 option,I want to know which option dose this?

and it seems javac can't do this?it seems javac support this constant folding:

```
int a=1+2+3
```

it will generate code a=6,but if code is:

```
int a=1;b=2;c=3;d=a+b+c
```

javac seems not have the ability that gcc O2 have,am I right?and is any compiler that aim is the stack machine(lua,clr) can't do the gcc O2 dose?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very useful to compare gcc and javac, because javac compiles to an intermediate language that is only converted to assembly at run-time.

Comment: @TimRoberts It is not 'converted to assembly' at all. It is converted straight to machine code. There is no assembly step.

Comment: Well, "machine code" in the sense of JVM.  It still has to get converted to native machine code at run-time.

Comment: As the manual says, "Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag."  This particular optimization might be enabled by `-O` or `-O2` yet not affected by any of the specific flags listed in the manual.